# Reporting Services is displaying extra rows for minimised row groups

Tags: reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

I have a fairly basic SQL Server Reporting Services report that is using nested row groups. Each sub-group depends on expanding its parent to be visible which is all pretty standard.  The layout is something like this:

> ```
> {      Company
> { {      Car  SUM(Price)
> { { {      Part  Price
> ```

My desired result when expanded is something like this (which I get fine):

> ```
> - SuperCarCompany
>   - SuperCar 20
>      Door 20
>   - SuperCar2 70
>      Door 30
>      Window 40
> - OtherCarCompany
>   - SuperCar2 50 /* Same SuperCar2 */
>     Door 50
> - MoreCarCompany
>   - BestCarEver 535
>      Engine 500
>      Door 30
>      Window 5
> ```

And when opened initially something like this:

> ```
> + SuperCarCompany
> + OtherCarCompany
> + MoreCarCompany
> ```

However, I'm getting this:

> ```
> + SuperCarCompany
>  + SuperCar2 70 (i.e. sum of all SuperCar2)
> + OtherCarCompany
>  + SuperCar 20
> + MoreCarCompany
>  + BestCarEver 535
> ```

and I can even expand these superfluous rows like this:

> ```
> + SuperCarCompany
>  - SuperCar2 70 (i.e. sum of all SuperCar2)
>     Door 30 (i.e. first child of any SuperCar2)
> ```

The superflous rows dissapear immediately when I expand the expected row above it (i.e. I'd need to expand all expected rows to get rid of all superflous rows).

Any idea on the cause?

Comment: Is there anything conflicting with the `Hidden` property of those rows maybe?

Comment: Well they don't even exist as real rows, they're getting made "magically"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to ensure that the control you use for expanding the rows happens to span both the minimised and the maximised rows.

For instance:

```
| |___|__| 
| |   |  |
```

Instead of:

```
|_|___|__|
| |   |  |
```